# My SharePoint 2010 SSRS Data Sources are being disabled, and I can't figure out why

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I am having a problem with SSRS data sources being mysteriously disabled in a SharePoint 2010, SSRS integrated-mode environment.

When I set up the data source, it is saved and I verify that it is enabled.  I can also successfully execute a report that uses that data source.  At some point later, it is disabled.  I can't figure out why, and it's driving me crazy.

Has anyone else experienced this?

My environment:

1. SharePoint 2010 Farm
2. One WFE
3. Two SharePoint-integrated SSRS app servers
4. One database server

Comment: Have come across before, don't rememeber exactly the fix, but try to republish the datasource again, or recreate the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Read this two articles:

1. Sharepoint dropping link to Data Source for SSRS reports
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91016bff-20e7-446a-bb70-7be407096faf/sharepoint-dropping-link-to-data-source-for-ssrs-reports
2. Reporting Services Data Source are getting disabled when deployed on SSRS Integrated mode
   http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742238/reporting-services-data-source-are-getting-disabled-when-deployed-on-ssrs-integrated-mode

In a nutshell:

It was related to some sort of problem with the Encrytion Keys set up in Reporting Services Configuration Manager .... Sharepoint Integration was also showing as Not Configured (despite the fact that it was working in Integration mode)

When I put in the Windows Account password under Windows Service Identity it once again prompted for saving the Encryption Key to a file ... once this was done Sharepoint Integration shows as Configured and the nightly problem (2AM when the Reporting Services daily maintenance programs run) goes away ....